# What should I do about wrong address in my UK visa application?

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications, pakistan

I am from Pakistan. My husband and I have applied for UK visit visas. I filled both applications. After submitting and paying, when I took the prints, I realized that I had made 3 minor (in my opinion) mistakes:

1. My husband visited France in September 2014. I checked *02* instead of *09* for month
2. I wrote my husband's personal cell number instead of his employer no.
3. I wrote the wrong postal code of our sponsor in my application.
4. I also write the wrong house no. of our sponsor in my application.

Now I have an appointment at Gerry's on 4th March for the application submission. I am really worried. Will these mistakes matter?

It's worth mentioning that I visited the UK in 2016 with my kids, and this time only me and my husband.

Comment: They don't sound like significant mistakes. But next time, you really should be more careful while filling in the forms.

Comment: My confidence killed me